# CSS doesn't appear to load when opening a local HTML page on mobile

Tags: android, css, mobile, html

I have a barebones, minimalist webpage that I run locally on my computer so that I can interface with my Spark Core ([older version of the Photon](https://store.particle.io/)) and my functions exposed through the Cloud API.

The HTML is completely bare--I don't need a whole bunch of things on there. Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen">
    <title>Spark</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sparkjs/1.0.0/spark.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div onclick="functionPost('function', 'argument')">
      <h1>Spark</h1>
      <br>
      <div id="node">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS file is in the same directory as the HTML file on both my computer and my phone.

*I have an empty `<p></p>` element in there so that I can populate it with returned data from the JSON response with a DOM injection. That is handled through Javascript and doesn't have any bearing on my issue. I just wanted to mention that before anyone points it out.*

I don't have this hosted as I have an access token embedded into it so I can validate through the Cloud API. Hosting it locally works perfect for me.

I built and tested all of this on my laptop. However, when I brought it over to my phone, the Javascript works but the CSS doesn't appear to load at all.

I'm not much of a web developer but I can get my way around. I was able to make it work, both in stylization and in behaviour, but I don't know why it doesn't work on my phone.

One thing I noticed is that when I run the HTML file from the directory on my phone, this shows up in the URL bar:

```
content://0@media/external/file/7320
```

So, I'm not exactly sure how the mobile platform is treating that file as it doesn't show it having an HTML extension.

I am using Chrome version 54.0.2840.71 m and Windows 10 Home edition on my computer and I am using Chrome version 54.0.2840.68 on Android 6.0.1.

EDIT: I also wanted to add that the only handles I am accessing in the CSS file are:

```
body {}

h1 {}

p {}

#node {}

*{}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full url to the css fill rather than a relative path?

Comment: @Omega I tried the "/storage/1234-9876/Site/style.css" but that didn't work. That is the file path but the URI path displayed when I run the site is different.